# Does Blender have a similar node to Unity's Scene Depth node?

Tags: shaders, shader-nodes

[Video](https://youtu.be/NiOGWZXBg4Y?t=205) for reference.

I'm trying to make a shader that needs to get data based on its intersections, like that forcefield shader in the linked video. I've looked if there were any tutorials doing this, but nothing too helpful. The closest thing was the Fresnel node, but that doesn't interact with the scene in any way either.

So is there a node, or a combination of nodes, that'll achieve this look of emission at intersecting scene geometry?

Comment: The depth is Z-depth in Blender. You will find it in the Compositor, not in the Shader editor.